# How can I use a managed DLL without loading the CLR?

Tags: .net, c++, windows, winapi

If I have a managed DLL and an unmanaged Explorer extension, is it possible to load the managed DLL somehow without pulling the CLR into Explorer's process space?

I understand that writing a managed Explorer extension is a no-no as it loads the CLR into Explorer and causes issues with any other plugins/extensions that happen to use the CLR, but I have some managed code that I would like to use in my extension. How can I avoid the problem?

Comment: Managed DLLs run using the CLR. Using a managed DLL without the CLR is like trying to fly an airplane with no air. In short: It can't be done. You'll have to use some sort of remoting to get the desired result.

Comment: The in-process side-by-side support in .NET 4.0 was designed to solve this problem.  Ironically Microsoft later declared using this to write shell extensions an unsupported usage.  Well, it is not like you're going to get much support getting an out-of-process solution working.  http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=jialiang%20shell%20extensions&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fgeekswithblogs.net%2FJialiang%2Farchive%2F2010%2F09%2F16%2Fwriting-windows-shell-extension-with-.net-4---part-1.aspx&ei=-xWfToX9EuOSiQLD1Nxl&usg=AFQjCNFlQ4Hz-QCRfPYYHuCtmQbsokjVHQ&cad=rja

Comment: Funny question. If that was possible, why would we ever use "the CLR"? To be picky, in fact, you can *load* it, but not *execute* it :-)

Comment: I was really wondering if it's possible to load it "Out of process" somehow (hence mentioning LoadLibrary in the title) without interfering with any other version loaded by Explorer. As mentioned above, SxS was a possibility but doesn't look like it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an ideal answer, but a route you could consider nonetheless.  Write an unmanaged proxy and call into a managed code service using named pipes / other IPC.  It is a bit tacky and smells but if you are stuck..

Comment: To be honest, it's the IPC I'm trying to do via managed. If I were to go down that route I might as well communicate directly. I'm struggling to find a suitable IPC method to communicate between a C# service and a C++ extension.

Comment: Have you gotten far with named pipes?  It's in theory as simple as using the nice managed wrappers and ReadFile/WriteFile in the unmanaged code.  You need to (de-)seralise yourself, of course..

Comment: That's where the problem is, I'm using WCF for the named pipe server which uses undocumented methods for naming the pipes as well as serialisation. I think shared memory is my best bet after looking into DCOM but I've never used shared memory before so it's going to be a learning curve.

Comment: You were right to suggest another method of communication, it seems silly to try to load the CLR just for named pipe communications when I can just setup a standard named pipe server and use that.

Answer (score 0):

You can always wait until Windows 8. WinRT is totally unmanaged and the API syntax is very much like .NET

Comment: And then wait until everyone upgrades. And anyway, all earlier versions of Windows are unmanaged too.